# Iterate through each set (container) of a set to match and even their height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

My page contains various sections and within each section there are  elements spread over columns. The number of columns for each section depends.

```
<header>this is my page header</header>
<section>
    <div class="columns three">
        <article>first article, with image title and excerpt</article>
        <article>second article, with image title and excerpt</article>
        <article>third article, with image title and excerpt</article>
    </div>
</section>
<section>
    <div class="columns five">
        <article>first article, with image title and excerpt</article>
        <article>second article, with image title and excerpt</article>
        <article>third article, with image title and excerpt</article>
        <article>fourth article, with image title and excerpt</article>
        <article>fifth article, with image title and excerpt</article>
    </div>
</section>
<section>
    <div class="columns four">
        <article>first article, with image title and excerpt</article>
        <article>second article, with image title and excerpt</article>
        <article>third article, with image title and excerpt</article>
        <article>fourth article, with image title and excerpt</article>
    </div>
</section>
```

What I want is a jQuery function that will go through each SECTION and match heights of its article children within that section. I managed to do it over the entire page but I cannot manage to make it within each group only.

```
var hEqualize = 0;
jQuery('section article').each(function() {
    hEqualize = jQuery(this).height() > hEqualize ? jQuery(this).height() : hEqualize;
}).height(hEqualize);
```

Let me know with what tweaks I could make this work because i am not familiar with JS and jQuery at all.

Comment: you mean to say that the height of each article in a section should be same (but can be different in different sections). Right?

Comment: Than I think you should `each` your `section` instead of `article`. Don't you?!

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I tried but it does not work at all, i basically need to iterate through each section, then through each child of this section. But can't find the right syntax :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can break this into two loops. One for section. The other for articles within the section.

```
var hEqualize = 0;
$('section').each(function () {
    hEqualize = 0;
    $(this).find('article').each(function () {
        hEqualize = jQuery(this).height() > hEqualize ? jQuery(this).height() : hEqualize;
    }).height(hEqualize);
    console.log(hEqualize);
});
```

See jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/taleebanwar/gv05fsw0/)

Answer (score 0):

As I've said in comments:
you should `each` over your `section` instead.

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/logaro/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output)***

```
jQuery(function($) { // DOM ready and Free to use $ now :)

$('section').each(function() {
    var hEqualize = 0;
    $(this).find("article").each(function(){
       var myH = $(this).height();
       hEqualize = myH > hEqualize ? myH  : hEqualize;
    }).height(hEqualize)
});

});
```

Or you can even simplify a bit your jQuery code:

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/logaro/2/edit?html,css,js,console,output)***

```
jQuery(function($) { // DOM ready and Free to use $ now :)

  $('section').each(function() {

    var hEQ = 0;
    $(this).find("article").height(function(i, v){
      hEQ = v>hEQ ? v : hEQ;
    }).height( hEQ );

  });

});
```